# Facing issue with cron job in magento 2.2.7, how to solve?

Tags: magento2.2.7

I am getting below error in update.cron.log file.

> [2020-01-20 05:33:01] update-cron.ERROR: Cron readiness check failure!
>   Found non-writable paths:     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/.github
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/.htaccess.sample
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/.php_cs.dist
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/.travis.yml
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/.user.ini
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/CHANGELOG.md
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/COPYING.txt
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/Gruntfile.js.sample
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/LICENSE.txt
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/LICENSE_AFL.txt
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/app/design/adminhtml/Magento
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/app/design/frontend/Magento
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/dev/tests/acceptance
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/dev/tests/integration/_files
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/nginx.conf.sample
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/package.json.sample
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/php.ini.sample
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/pub/static/.htaccess
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/var/.htaccess
>     /var/www/vhosts/project/webroot/vendor/.htaccess [] []

Answer (score 0):

The issue about of file ***does not give write permission*** so run bellow command in **Magento root** directory:

```
chmod -R 777 .github
chmod -R 777 pub var generated
```

Comment: let me try once

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens because of the ownership is not right at your system.

The user (like apache) from where your add your cronjob, does not have  write & read issue. So, you have to provide that user to the right access to run cron job and that user must have the permission of access like Web user access & permission.

### Example:

Suppose, you have web user apache i.e www-data and you can run cronjob from that www-data, then try below code:

> sudo crontab -u www-data php bin/magento cron:install --force

**Checkout below like regarding this topic:**

https://askubuntu.com/questions/189189/how-to-run-crontab-as-userwww-data/210545

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html